# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Electrical Engineering's [3rd moderator election](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Nick Alexeev] [image: Dave Tweed]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4911108674551808/0).

Comment: @madmanguruman - you were our runner up and only a tiny bit short.

Comment: Congrats to Dave and Nick!

Comment: @Kortuk Of course I was. It's my role here.

Comment: @Madmanguruman It has not happened here before, but if we have someone step down in the near future or a large increase in load they normally invite the runner up to join. You were very close this time! Get the number of flags up and I am sure you are a shoe in. :)

Comment: I demand a recount!

Comment: @Passerby A recount would probably land me in 4th .. shhh :)

Comment: Thaks you for the time you are spend to watch this excellent forum

Answer (score 7):

Good luck to the new fellows! May the diamond be with you!